# Sympy Subs not replacing a symbol when its power is being replaced

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to make some basic substitutions but SymPy doesn't want to help me out

```
x, y, z, k = symbols("x y z k", positive=True, real=True)
exp = x**4 + x**3 + x**2 + x
what_im_expecting = simplify(y**(Rational(1/4)) + y**(Rational(3/4)) + sqrt(y) + y)
what_i_actually_get = exp.subs(x**4,y)
exp, what_i_actually_get, what_im_expecting
```

returns

```
x + y**(Rational(3, 4)) + sqrt(y) + y
```

[image]

Can anyone help me out?

---

---

a more complex example:

[image]

Comment: I get your point in the first example, but it's unclear what result you expected in the second.

Comment: One more thing: `Rational(3/4)` should be `Rational(3, 4)`. Otherwise the division evaluates to a float first, for example `sp.Rational(1/5)` is `3602879701896397/18014398509481984`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `subs` can be trusted to replace the terms that exactly match the given "old" expression, which `x**4` here. The replacement of other things related to `x**4` is not so certain. (There are [many open issues](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+subs+) with subs: some say it substitutes too much, some say too little.) There is some substitution logic specific to *powers*, but `x` by itself is not formally a *power*, so it escapes that logic.  A workaround: temporarily replace `x` by `x**1`, preventing automatic evaluation of that power to `x`.

```
x1 = sp.Pow(x, 1, evaluate=False)
subbed = exp.subs(x, x1).subs(x**4, y).subs(x1, x)
```

Now `subbed` is `y**(3/4) + y**(1/4) + sqrt(y) + y`.

But, don't expect human-like ingenuity from `subs`. With the same workaround, trying to do `subs(x**4 - 1, y)` results in `x**3 + x**2 + x + y + 1`: nothing like `sqrt(y+1)`, etc, appears. It's better to substitute in the most direct way possible:

```
subs(x, (y+1)**Rational(1, 4))
```

Then you don't need any workarounds.