# Why isn't Sympy subs() working consistently?

Tags: python, sympy, substitution

I am wondering why Sympy's subs() doesn't seem to work in the following particular case. Here's the MWE:

```py
import sympy as sy

L_ee, L_es, L_ev, L_ss, L_sv, L_vv, X, Y, Z, J_e, J_s, J_v = sy.symbols('L_ee L_es L_ev L_ss L_sv L_vv X Y Z J_e J_s J_v')

eq1 = sy.Eq(J_e, -L_ee * X - L_es * Y - L_ev * Z)
eq2 = sy.Eq(J_s, -L_es * X - L_ss * Y - L_sv * Z)
eq3 = sy.Eq(J_v, -L_ev * X - L_sv * Y - L_vv * Z)

sol1 = sy.solve(eq3, Z)

# Replace Z into the 1st eq.
eq1 = eq1.subs(Z, sol1[0])

sol2 = sy.solve(eq1, X)
eq2 = eq2.subs(X, sol2[0])

eq2 = eq2.subs([(Z, sol1[0]), (X, sol2[0])])
eq2 = sy.factor(eq2, (Y, J_v, J_e))

T, bismuth = sy.symbols('T bismuth')
flux_eq = sy.Eq(T*eq2.lhs, T*eq2.rhs)
eq2_flux = flux_eq.subs([(J_v, 0), (J_e, 0)])

bismuth_exp = sy.symbols('bismuth_exp')
bismuth_exp = -eq2_flux.rhs / Y
print(eq2_flux.rhs)

# Works as expected here
print(eq2_flux.rhs.subs(bismuth_exp, bismuth), type(eq2_flux.rhs.subs(bismuth_exp, bismuth)))
print(bismuth_exp)

# But then, why doesn't it work here?
print(eq2.rhs.subs(bismuth_exp, bismuth), type(eq2.rhs.subs(bismuth_exp, bismuth)))
```

My goal is to write eq2.rhs in terms of "bismuth". In the above code, I first make "bismuth" appear in an expression very similar to eq2.rhs, which is eq2_flux.rhs. So I print that expression first, and then I print the same expression with bismuth. I get "-Y*bismuth" which is correct, i.e. Sympy has no problem to make "bismuth" appear in eq2_flux.rhs

When I try the exact same thing with eq2.rhs, "bismuth" never substitutes the huge chunk it should. By eyes, I should get something like -J_e(something) - J_v(something else) - bismuth * Y / T.

Note that I print the type of each eq.rhs and they match. So I am really clueless on what's going on and wondering whether Sympy isn't able to substitute the very same chunk for "bismuth" in an expression very similar to one it is able to do.

In response to the comment that possibly the expression to be replaced should appear as is, here's an example equivalent to my case, but which works:

```py
x, y, z, v = sy.symbols('x y z v')
test = x + y + (v/2.0)*z
print(test.subs(z, 3.0/5 *v))
```

In that case, z is correctly substituted.

I have added "+Y" to eq2_flux and the substitution still works, yet eq2_flux isn't a constant times bismuth in that case. I correctly get "-Y*bismuth + Y". Very puzzling to say the least.

Comment: I'm not sure but this could be a general problem. Apparently ( see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730086/sympy-subs-not-replacing-a-symbol-when-its-power-is-being-replaced) subs can only be trusted to replace expressions of the exact form given. Your second try requires conversions. In the first equation, up to constant, bismuth_exp is literally your expression, so it somehow matches it I guess.

Comment: @Banana I have added a short MWE equivalent to my case, but which works. Not sure what's going on. P.S.: I just tried to add "+T" to eq2_flux and the substitution still works fine. In this case the expression is not a constant times kappa_exp, yet it works. Extremely puzzling.

Comment: I dont know the answer, but that post suggests what is _guaranteed_, not what fails. All I'm saying is that this method seems to have many open issues ( https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues?utf8=✓&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+subs+ ). Have you tried solving your expression for a variable first and then substitute it maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't assume that subs will be able to match something that isn't literally part of your expression e.g.:

```
In [54]: (x**3).subs(x**2, 1) 
Out[54]: 
 3
x
```

There are some situations where it will work e.g.

```
In [55]: (x**4).subs(x**2, 1)
Out[55]: 1
```

but this kind of replacement will always be flaky in general so I wouldn't depend on it.

With that in mind you need to ensure that the first argument to subs is a literal node in the expression tree. Then it is guaranteed that subs will find all instances of it and substitute them. In your case we can do that with

```
In [114]: F = T/(L_ee*L_vv-L_ev**2)

In [115]: eq2.rhs.subs(bismuth_exp/F, bismuth/F)
Out[115]: 
 ⎛                                                              ⎛             2⎞⎞ 
 ⎜                                                    Y⋅bismuth⋅⎝Lₑₑ⋅Lᵥᵥ - Lₑᵥ ⎠⎟ 
-⎜Jₑ⋅(-Lₑₛ⋅Lᵥᵥ + Lₑᵥ⋅Lₛᵥ) + Jᵥ⋅(-Lₑₑ⋅Lₛᵥ + Lₑₛ⋅Lₑᵥ) + ──────────────────────────⎟ 
 ⎝                                                                T             ⎠ 
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                               2                                  
                                  Lₑₑ⋅Lᵥᵥ - Lₑᵥ                                   

In [116]: signsimp(_.apart(bismuth)).collect([J_e, J_v])
Out[116]: 
Jₑ⋅(Lₑₛ⋅Lᵥᵥ - Lₑᵥ⋅Lₛᵥ) + Jᵥ⋅(Lₑₑ⋅Lₛᵥ - Lₑₛ⋅Lₑᵥ)   Y⋅bismuth
─────────────────────────────────────────────── - ─────────
                              2                       T    
                 Lₑₑ⋅Lᵥᵥ - Lₑᵥ
```

which looks like the form you were expecting.

Comment: I see... The very sad thing is that I must manually define F. It's like, there's no way to automate stuff from A to Z. Any manual tweak and it's essentially "a loss". Nevertheless, I accept your answer (and upvote it), for it has nothing to do with the way Sympy works.

Comment: The question is how you define what substitution is supposed to happen. I can get a different result with say `eq2.rhs.subs(L_ee, solve(bismuth_exp-bismuth, L_ee)[0])` which eliminates `L_ee`. If you can define the rules for what substitution you want then it might be possible to do that automatically.Sympy will not choose between ambiguous possibilities for you.

Comment: A MWE for the substitutions you are doing is `(a*T*n/d).subs(T*n/d, u)` vs `(A/d).subs(T*n/d, u)`...and this underscores the ambiguity of the replacement in the second case.